# .htaccess for wampserver 3.0.6 not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I am currently using Wampserver 3.0.6 to build this website. I finished the whole thing but the URL re-writing is a bit of a pickle for me. 
I have put the .htaccess file in the root directory of my website files(not in the root directory of Wampserver).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Its not showing me the output I desire. I turned on the re-write mode in Apache httpd.conf file still no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: these are not errors, these are the logs for shutting down and restarting Apache.

Comment: Sorry am just an amateur on this topic. But .htaccess file is still not working for me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: change the third line like this and check it again: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: i did but its still not working. Are there any files i need to enable or disable on wamp 3.0,6 aside from the rewrite-module on Apache which i already enabled? I just want to get rid of the .php extension from every file on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This worked perfect for me.